# OpenFace without command line interaction

Tags: python

I am training my own classifier using [OpenFace](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/demo-3-classifier/). It is working fine for me but i don't want to pass the pickle file and image from my command like i want it to specify the pickle file path and image path. I have gone through the code it is using **argparse**. I am not able to understand how i can specify the path without passing any arguments in command line.
I tried `nargs=?` to make it optional arguments but i am not able to do it as still it is showing `error: too few arguments`.

Please help as how i can achieve this.

Comment: **Post your code and explain the specific problem**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't work the way you want.
You can modify the code for your needs. This is not so difficult for your case.

For the pickled classifier model command line input option you can keep it in a file, read that (in binary format `open(<path>, 'rb')` and use it instead of `args.classifierModel` (wherever you see in that code), and remove it from the argument parser (ie remove line

```
inferParser.add_argument(
    'classifierModel',
    type=str,...
```

Do the same for image path, remove line

```
 inferParser.add_argument('imgs', type=str, nargs='+',inferParser.add_argument('imgs', type=str, nargs='+',...
```

Replace args.imgs by list of your image paths and it should work.